# Web Development - Is there a way to force a page refresh?

Tags: web-testing

As you develop a website, you will be making lots of changes to your pages. This can create a problem if your browser decides to cache the page and use an old one. Often times you want the newest one.

You can delete your whole cache by going to settings->content->clear browsing data and selecting "Cache" in the list, etc.

The problem is that this takes a ling time, especially if you only need one page changed. What is more, you don't really want to clear all the cache, just the one page. Is there a quick and easy way to only clear the cache of the problem page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is!

Per [Kinsta:](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/how-to-clear-browser-cache/#single)

> Before you go straight to clearing your entire browser cache, one trick you can try is something called a “force refresh”.

and later:

> - Windows and Linux browsers: CTRL + F5
> - Apple Safari: SHIFT + Reload toolbar button
> - Chrome and Firefox for Mac: CMD + SHIFT + R
>
> Again, this method only bypasses the cache for the specific page that you’re on. It leaves the rest of your browser cache untouched.